# Polynomials with Integer coefficients distinct powers of 2

Tags: polynomials

Prove that for every natural number n, there exists a polynomial p(x) with integer coefficients such that p(1), p(2),......,p(n) are distinct powers of 2.

Comment: Maybe you could use an induction argument, but I am not sure. It would be helpful iy you include your thoughts so far.

Comment: Have you tried a few cases of small $n$?  Often that brings illumination.

Comment: Try Lagrange interpolation.

Comment: Check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680450/integer-coefficient-polynomial-values-as-powers-of-2?rq=1, there is a constructive proof.

Comment: The claimed duplicate has an answer that is not appropriate.  It proves there is not polynomial that takes only powers of $2$ at all integers.  It does not deal with the finite case this question (and that question) asks about.  There is a  comment that $n=12$ works.